# How to clear a selection of definitions from UpValues?

Tags: evaluation, upvalues, clear

I'm trying to set up a bunch of 2D points using [*`UpSet`*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSet.html) that I am going to use later for building lines and graphs.

```
Clear[coords, point]
coords[point[0]] = {3, 2.3};
coords[point[1]] = {8, 3.43};
```

etc. Also, I'm using the same approach to set up some basic characteristics for my shapes, eg. their color, `PointSize` etc.

```
Clear[color, size]

(* colors *)
color[point[0]] ^= Blend[{Yellow, Magenta}, 0.25];
color[point[1]] ^= Blend[{Cyan, Yellow}, 0.75];

(* sizes *)
size[point[0]] ^= PointSize[0.025];
size[point[1]] ^= PointSize[0.035];
```

Now, I figured it would be *easier* to automate some part of the process eg. for making points, again using `UpSet`

```
(* make points *)
point /* ({#, size[#], color[#], Point[coords[#]]} &) /* 
  (Through[{First /* graphics, Rest /* Graphics}[#]] &) /* 
    Apply[UpSet] /@ Range[0, 1]
```

**but** it's not working how I was expecting it to behave: every time I re-evaluate the code snippet that creates my points (ie. the code shown above), I get an `UpSet::write` error.

From what I gather, the first time that the code executes, it performs the expected assignments, ie it uses`graphic[point[n]]` to assign to the `UpValues` of `point` the associated `Graphics` object, but from there on, any future evaluation prematurely (for my purposes) evaluates the part inside `... Through[{First /* graphics, ...}] ...` and when it's time for `... Apply[UpSet] ...` to do the job, it fails because it's not seeing

```
graphics[point[...]] ^= {graphics primitives...}
```

but it actually gets

```
Graphics[{...}] ^= {graphics primitives}
```

and since the contents of `Graphics` are inside a `List`, the kernel complains with the `UpSet::write` that "*Tag List in <it actually displays a graphic> is Protected*", letting me know I don't have access to the `UpValues` of `List`, which makes sense, but I wasn't trying to do that!

My first instinct was to try and clear the definitions of `graphics[point[n]]` before every new assignment, but I couldn't and this is when I realized I was having a problem of premature evaluation on my hands.

My ugly solution is to clear the definitions before re-evaluation using the following helper function `unset`, which removes the relevant definitions from `UpValues` before I re-insert them, using the code in the code snippet `(* make points *)` above:

```
Clear[unset]

SetAttributes[unset, HoldFirst]

unset[head_[expr_[n_]]] := Module[{upvalues},
  upvalues = UpValues[expr];
  UpValues[expr] = {};
  UpValues[expr] = Cases[upvalues, Except[_[head[expr[n]]] :> _]];
]
point /* graphics /* unset /@ Range[0, 1]
```

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the easiest way I can think of, without restructuring your code so that everything is evaluated at the right time, and without playing around with tricky `Unevaluated` wrappers: **use inactivated versions of the symbols that are evaluating prematurely** when building the expression, then `Activate` them once it's built. We'll use the `Inactive` versions of `UpSet` and `point`:

```
Inactive[point] /* ({#, size[#], color[#], Point[coords[#]]} &) /* 
  (Through[{First /* graphics, Rest /* Graphics}[#]] &) /* 
  Apply[Inactive[UpSet]] /@ Range[0, 1] // Activate
```

This works here for a couple reasons (some of which could break in other situations):

1. `Graphics` doesn't complain or evaluate to a `Failure` when supplied with non-graphical arguments, so it's okay to have `Inactive[point]` inside it for a bit; otherwise, we might have had to use `Inactive[Graphics]` as well
2. `UpSet` evaluates its second argument before assigning the upvalue, so we get a good `Graphics` expression, as e.g. `size[point[...]]` is given the chance to evaluate to a valid graphics primitive after activation
3. `Activate` doesn't have any `Hold*` attributes, so its argument evaluates fully before anything is `Activate`d

There are lots of other ways, e.g. using `Unevalauted` at the right times, using `Hold`s, and using functions with hold attributes (e.g. `Function[Null, ..., HoldAll]` instead of the `#`/`&` ones), but this seems simplest to me.

Comment: yes, I see what you did there! it definitely is more elegant than my slash-and-burn `unset`; I'd add an `Activate` between `Rest` and `Graphics` eg `Through[{..., Rest/*Activate/*Graphics}[...]]` because in my machine `Graphics` with `Inactive` contents shows as a red square that displays a `Tooltip` complaining about the `Inactive` expressions, when the `Activate` is not present; however there are no messages generated, so it's silent enough, I guess. This was a mental unblock answer for me; somehow I forgot all about `Hold` etc; thanks!